# How do I install packages/modules for Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm super new to Python, and can't figure out how to install packages or modules. I know you can use Pip to easily install them, but none of the commands I've found have done anything but give me errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post more details, what command did you run to install the module?  What error did it give you?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `pip install`? A good thing to remember is pip usually requires `sudo` on linux distributions. Also, for some modules it's easier to use [conda](https://conda.io/docs/), since it takes care of dependencies. It this is the best *general* information I can give. If you told me some packages you've tried to install, that would help a lot!